# Facebookads API : missing Insight video fields?

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights

I'm currently using the facebookads api 2.5.1 with python and I'm struggling with Insights fields for video ads.

I'm requesting Insights in async mode like this :

```
        i_async_job = campaign.get_insights(
            fields=fields,
            params={'time_range':{'since': from_date,'until': to_date},'level':'ad'},
            async=True)
```

and I'm passing fields parameters like :

```
        Insights.Field.spend,
        Insights.Field.video_avg_sec_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_avg_pct_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_p25_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_p50_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_p75_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_p95_watched_actions,
        ...
```

it works but when I try to get these following fields :

```
        Insights.Field.website_clicks,
        Insights.Field.video_10_sec_watched_actions,
        Insights.Field.video_30_sec_watched_actions,
```

it does not work... :-(
I've looked at the module sources and indeed, these fields are not present. 
The only way to get these fields is to fire again a new Insight query but with an empty field array. You have to parse then the result json to extract these missing metrics....

mmmmh.. am I doing something wrong or could I get these stats in one query ? Thanks.

Regards

Nicolas

Comment: sounds like an omission, just create an issue on the GitHub page and someone will take a look at adding them. You could alternatively create a pull request if you want to contribute! :)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will create a pull request for these missing fields ;-)